# asp.net app in virtual directory to look for bin folder in parent website in iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Say we have an asp.net web app deployed in iis7 like the following.
 ParentWebSite
              VirtulDirectory

The web.config in 'ParentWebSite' is automatically inherited in "VirtulDirectory".
How can we force the "bin" folder to be also be inherited.The "VirtulDirectory" would also have its own "bin" folder.and dlls present in "ParentWebSite" should be visible also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few solutions:

1) [Create symbolic link](https://serverfault.com/questions/7109/how-do-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-windows)

2) Install DLLs into GAC

Hope these help!